# Lever and principle of moments

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, equilibrium

Consider an ideal lever which consists of a rod pivoted at its fulcrum as shown in the picture.
[image]

Without any rigorous justification the textbook I am reading mentions that,
$$F_{1}d_{1}=F_{2}d_{2}$$
And says that the system is in mechanical equilibrium and the equation is a consequence of it.

**My question:-**

$(1)-Can we prove that the system is in mechanical equilibrium?

Comment: The proof of Arquimedes is very convincing to me. It is worth to spend some time to follow his argument: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Equilibrium_of_Planes

Answer (score 0):

Mechanical equilibrium means the body is in "uniform translational and rotational motion".  For a body initially at rest, as here, the body remains at rest. The system is in mechanical equilibrium if (a) the total force is zero and (b) the total torque is zero.  Your relationship (1) satisfies requirement (b).  The two downward forces $F_1$ and $F_2$ are countered by the upward force at the fulcrum of $F_1 + F_2$ so requirement (a) is satisfied.

Comment: Did you mean no CHANGE in motion? Can't we have equilibrium with motion as long as the motion is constant?

Comment: Yes, thanks.   I added the general definition per Symon, Mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete @John Darby’s answer, the two conditions of equilibrium (compensating force and compensating torque) may seem a bit parachuted for a newcomer. These conditions and the relevance of torque can be proved using the principle of virtual work. This is the path taken in the Feynman’s Lectures (Book 1, Chapter 18-2).

Hope this helps and tell me if you find some mistakes.